# Is it possible use Yii booster form component without model?

Tags: php, html, ajax, yii, yii-components

Is it possible use `Yii booster` form component without model?

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'textField',
        array('hint'=>'In addition to freeform text, any HTML5 text-based input appears like so.')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use TbForm instead of TbActiveForm in the widget if you want to create a form without ActiveRecord. TbActiveForm expects an ActiveRecord model whereas TbForm doesn't.

If you just want to use an individual element, you can always fall back to [CHtml::textField()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#textField-detail).